# mpi4py send and recv by the same process

Tags: python-3.x, mpi4py

According to MPI docs, messages can be sent and received by the same process.

What I have tried is:

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank=comm.Get_rank()
size=comm.Get_size()

test_list = np.zeros(4)

comm.send(rank, dest=0, tag=10+rank)

if rank == 0:
    for rnk in range(0, size):
        tmp = comm.recv(source=rnk, tag=10+rnk)
        test_list[rnk] = tmp
    print(test_list)
```

which hangs and can't get any results, with command

> mpirun -n 4 python3 xxx.py

So, I put rank 0 out of the operation, which makes the code really ugly.

```
test_list = np.zeros(4)

if rank != 0:
    comm.send(rank, dest=0, tag=10+rank)

comm.Barrier()

if rank == 0:
    for rnk in range(1, size):
        tmp = comm.recv(source=rnk, tag=10+rnk)
        test_list[rnk] = tmp
    print(test_list)
```

Is there any way to achieve this elegantly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!